# Cast Any to Array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm initializing a class by loading data from a `Map<String, Any>` in Kotlin.  As this Map is gleaned directly from JSON, I don't know for certain that any given key exists, or that its value is of the type I expect.  To unpack this Map safely I'm doing the following, which appears to work perfectly:

```
a = rawData["A"] as? String ?: ""
```

Some of this data is in further nested JSON, which I'm unpacking to Arrays; I've tried to do this in the same way:

```
b = rawData["B"] as? Array<String> ?: arrayOf<String>()
```

However, when I attempt this using an array (as above) IntelliJ kicks up a fuss, saying

> Warning:(111, 30) Kotlin: Unchecked cast: Any? to Array<String>

Is this just the IDE getting itself in a twist or is this method genuinely unsafe for Arrays despite being seemingly perfectly safe for other types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was ready to call this a bug, because `Array` is a reified type, meaning its generic parameter can actually be checked at runtime (unlike a `List`, for example). I've tried looking to see if it's been filed yet, and it turns out the compiler is actually right to show you a warning. As you can see in the response to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11948), there's still a nullability problem with casts of this kind.

```
val a = arrayOf("foo", "bar", null) as Array<String>
println(a[2].length)
```

Arrays like the one in this example are successfully cast (using `as`, they don't throw an exception, using `as?`, they don't return `null`), however, the cast can not ensure that this is an `Array<String>`, only that it's an `Array<String?>`.

This means that you can later read `null` values from a variable that is typed as an `Array<String>` after the cast, with no further warnings from the compiler.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way to safely cast to `Array<String>` without having to individually check each element for `null`?

Comment: I believe that there isn't. There are probably a couple different solutions in terms of syntax and strategies for when to do them, but I'm pretty sure that they have to be done for all elements that you use at some point.

Comment: Ok, my understanding of your answer was that the cast was unsafe because the element could still be null, meaning that a similar cast to `Array<String?>` would then be safe.  However IntelliJ is throwing the same warning with that, `Unchecked cast: Any? to Array<String?>`.  Have I misunderstood your answer or is there something different now going on here?

Comment: @CaileanWilkinson that's what the mentioned issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11948 is about: a cast to `Array<String?>` could be checked on JVM.

Comment: @Ilya Sorry, I don’t understand what you mean.  The cast to Array<String?> is producing the same warning as the cast to Array<String>

Comment: Let me correct the previous comment: a cast to `Array<out String?>` could be checked. It could be, but it isn't now. Note that out-projection is the key here.

Answer (score 16):

For any future readers of this question, to expand on the accepted answer with a solution:

To safely cast Any to an array of a particular type in Kotlin, you have to first cast to an untyped array (see zsmb13's answer above for why), and then filter that array to the desired type.

For example, to cast `input: Any` to an array of `String` instances, you would call:

```
val inputAsArray = (input as? Array<*>)?.filterIsInstance<String>()
```