# ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]

Tags: kotlin

I used one of the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086786/cast-any-to-array-in-kotlin) to get help with previous error but now I'm getting another one. There's a suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984997/java-util-arraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-object) to this question but I'm unable to get solution out of it for my problem.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Object[]

```
private var data: Any? // fixed, can't change data type as it's in a compiled library to accept all kinds of data.

fun users() : ArrayList<User> {
    return (data as Array<*>).filterIsInstance<User>() as ArrayList<User>
}
```

---

After the suggestions in the comment, the working code looks like this but I've another side effect, I can't add items to the array, the ArrayList remains empty.

```
fun users() : ArrayList<User> {
    return (data as ArrayList<*>).filterIsInstance<User>() as ArrayList<User>
}

fun addItem(userVO: User) {
    users().add(user)
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

```
val users: ArrayList<User> get() = ((data as? ArrayList<Any>)?.filterIsInstance<User>() ?: emptyList()) as ArrayList<User>

fun addItem(user: User) {
    users.add(user)
}
```

Comment: what is `data`?

Comment: it is `var data: Any?`, adding to my question

Comment: why are you trying to cast to `Array` if you store `ArrayList` in `data`?

Comment: you mean it should be `return (data as ArrayList<*>).filterIsInstance<User>() as ArrayList<User>`

Comment: also I've another side effect, I've an `addItem` method, and I don't seem to be able to add items, the ArrayList remains empty, `fun users()` is a getter function

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: because `filterIsInstance` returns a new `ArrayList` to which you add your `user`

Comment: I see, I'm confused now what to do and how to solve my both problems, I'm new to kotlin

Comment: if you store `ArrayList<User>` in your `data`, just `fun users() : ArrayList<User> {
    return (data as ArrayList<User>)
}`

Comment: @IR42 yes that I had in the first place but it gives me warning, `Unchecked cast: Any? to kotlin.collections.ArrayList<User> /* = java.util.ArrayList<User> *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having untyped `data` as a source is not the best idea but if you are working with a third-party library you might have no choice. In that case, you may try the following:

```
private var data: Any? = null

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val users: List<User> get() = (data as? ArrayList<Any>)?.filterIsInstance<User>() ?: emptyList()

fun addUser(user: User) {
   @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
   (data as? ArrayList<Any>)?.add(user)
}
```

In the above, I suppose that the `data` list may contain not only users but other entities also.

Comment: sorry, i still have the problem of having empty list because of filterIsInstance

Comment: @AppDeveloper if you use `addUser` function from my example then `filterIsInstance` can't be the problem. Can you describe your actions that lead to the "empty list because of filterIsInstance" problem?

Comment: Can you please update the code to use `ArrayList` in `val users: List<User>`, as I've remove method in use too

Comment: see my edit 2 please for the updated code. Intellij casted it for me. my add item calls the getter (unliked your example) that's why it ended up with 0 items.

Comment: Well, you can't add something into a filtered list and expect the new value in the original list. Just take a look at the `filterIsInstance` implementation and you will see that a new `ArrayList` is created there. I deliberately specify the immutable `List<User>` type for the `users` property to restrict any direct additions.